# read output of php file using python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a `php` file on server that prints some data from the `mysql` database in `json` format.

When I run my `php` file in my browser I can see the `json` array. Now I want to get that `json` array in a `python` file. Is there a way to do it?

here is the code i am using

```
import subprocess
import json
import codecs

proc = subprocess.Popen("http://www.rpi-connect.esy.es/getappliances?room=1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = str(proc.stdout.read().decode('utf8'))
print(script_response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the answer after trying a lot of different python libraries

```
import json
import urllib.request
url = "http://example.com/your-filename.php"
x = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
raw_data = x.read()
encoding = x.info().get_content_charset('utf8')  # JSON default
print(raw_data)   #this is data in string format
data = json.loads(raw_data.decode(encoding))
print(data)   #this would be your json data
```

this works for python 3.4. for python 2.7 try using json.load() instead of json.loads()

Answer (score 0):

Run the code with the following command and store its standard output to a variable:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/your/script.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

And if you need that data in json in python too:

```
import json
data = json.loads(script_response)
```

Comment: i am getting following error for json.load()Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MOHIT\Desktop\pyurl\url.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.loads(script_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: Try this instead: script_response = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf8') and do the rest.

Comment: i am getting no ouput just 2 blank lines I have put the code but this seems to get no output. You can use the link on your browser to see the json array

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If yes then please choose this as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having your PHP script output the JSON to a file on your server, then have your python script read that JSON in from the file.

You can achieve it like this:

### PHP Script:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode('your data');
$file = '/tmp/json-file';

file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

### Python script:

```
import json

with open('/tmp/json-file') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

    # do whatever you need to do with data here
```

Comment: I am trying you solution too. should the json-file be already present on server or php creates it on its own

Comment: The PHP script that I've included in my answer will take care of writing the file to the server. You should change the filepath `/tmp/json-file` to wherever you'd like the file to be written to on your environment.
PHP's `file_put_contents()` function will take care of creating the file if it doesn't already exist, and will also overwrite a file if one already exists at the location.

Comment: i am getting no ouput just 2 blank lines I have put the code but this seems to get no output. You can use the link on your browser to see the json array this is the file path http://www.rpi-connect.esy.es/jsondata